# Complicated spiral matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am training for my Google-interview and I try to understand this solution that came up in a video I watched. I would really appreciate if someone could explain what is happening here.

Here is the question: 
Write a function that accepts an integer N and returns a NxN spiral matrix.

Examples:

```
matrix(2)
[
  [1, 2],
  [4, 3]
]

matrix(3)
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [8, 9, 4],
  [7, 6, 5]
]

matrix(4)
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
]
```

Code:

```
function matrix(n) {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    results.push([]);
  }

  let counter = 1;
  let startColumn = 0;
  let endColumn = n - 1;
  let startRow = 0;
  let endRow = n - 1;
  while (startColumn <= endColumn && startRow <= endRow) {
    // Top row
    for (let i = startColumn; i <= endColumn; i++) {
      results[startRow][i] = counter;
      counter++;
    }
    startRow++;

    // Right column
    for (let i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
      results[i][endColumn] = counter;
      counter++;
    }
    endColumn--;

    // Bottom row
    for (let i = endColumn; i >= startColumn; i--) {
      results[endRow][i] = counter;
      counter++;
    }
    endRow--;

    // start column
    for (let i = endRow; i >= startRow; i--) {
      results[i][startColumn] = counter;
      counter++;
    }
    startColumn++;
  }

  return results;
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand ?

Comment: What's the video?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  If you have a specific point of confusion, then explain it.  A global "I don't understand" is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is made as follows :

- `results` is an array containing n arrays (it will be filled in the **while** loop).
- `counter` counts the number of visited matrix cells.
- `startColumn`, `endColumn`, `startRow`, `endRow` define the bounds of a rectangle that shrinks progressively when visiting the matrix cells. For example, when the first row is completely visited, `startRow` is incremented, so the first row no longer makes part of the rectangle.
- `while` condition means thats the rectangle bounds doesn't have to meet. In the opposite case, the rectangle would have 0 surface, so the matrix would only have visited cells, so it would be terminated.
- First `for` loop means "wipe the **top** border of the rectangle; each time you visit a new cell, assign `counter` as the cell's value and increment it".
- Second, third and fourth loop mean the same thing but for **right**, **bottom** and **left** borders.